# Threads in Simple iOS Application

Tags: ios

When I create empty application (with Single view template for example) and if some crash happens, it shows 5 threads in Debug Navigator like Thread-1, Thread-2, Thread-3, Thread-4, Thread-5. I understand Thread-1 which is main application thread, but what are these other threads?

Answer (score 1):

Those are internal threads which are required for every application. By default every app has some threads. In addition to those, you can create additional threads though through

NSTimers, performSelectors, dispatch_async, NSOperations etc

Comment: I understand these are default threads created for each app but I am interested to know what these threads exactly are for?